# Find Questions with Most Comments

Tags: discussion, sorting

Is there any way to list the top questions by the number of comments coming through?

Comment: Get 10k rep and look here: http://stackoverflow.com/tools/. It's just the most recent ones, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mmyers notes, you can see the most recent, most commented posts if you have access to the 10k tools.

Otherwise, [try statoverflow](http://statoverflow.com/sandbox/?q=Select%20id,%20title,%20commentcount%20From%20posts%20Where%20posttypeid=1%20Order%20By%20commentcount%20desc%20Limit%2020)...

Comment: ok that works...